# Problem to insert into mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have made a script to send messages. But the problem is it fails to insert into table when i type a bit longer message though i have set "mail" as VARCHAR and length 30005 .

I am using this query ..

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `mailbox` (`id` ,`receiver` ,`mail` ,`sender` ,`time` ,`date` ,`reply-from` ,`read-status` ,`sd` ,`rd`) VALUES ('', '$receiver_username', '$mail', '$sender_username', '$gmt_time', '$gmt_date', '$from_mail', '1', '', '')") or die("Couldnt Insert Data");
```

when type small message it is ok. otherwise it shows Couldnt Insert Data .

So please help me.

Recently i have checked its hapening bcz this two syntax ' and " . Now how two insert them i dont want to encode the texts

Comment: please share what is the exact error message you are getting (mysql_error()).

Comment: what is your `max_allowed_packet` setting ?

Comment: what is `type small message` also don't swallow exceptions while you are debugging code or ever for that matter

Comment: sorry, i have just run mysql_error() . and its saying this problem is because i am using this syntax ' "  at my message body . So now how to fix it .

Comment: @BoltClock - sorry i can't understand to you. please explain

Answer (score 0):

Length 30005 for a varchar field? that's impossible, varchar's max length is 255 characters. Try making the mail field a TEXT datatype.

Comment: Its max length has been pushed to 65,535 as of MySQL 5.0.3. 64 whole kilobytes of `VARCHAR`. Then again you're right, it should be a `TEXT` type.

Comment: Thanks for your reply .. let me try it

Comment: I have changed it to     TEXT  but its still same error  Its hapening bcz of ' and " . how to fix this two syntax

Answer (score 0):

You need to look on couple of things here.

1: You should save data data in database in text column rather varchar 30005
2: Look at all followings in PHP.ini file
upload_max_filesize:50M
max_execution_time:NONE
memory_limit:60M
post_max_size:55M

3: More help could be provided after you show actuall error by mysql_error()

Comment: i have just run mysql_error() . and its saying this problem is because i am using this syntax ' " at my message body . So now how to fix it . I dont want to encode them

Comment: I'm unable to understand your problem with that less info. Kindly elaborate more on it. To me it looks you're misquoting from your error but can not say anything with provided info.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the long text you are trying to insert has singles quotes `'` or other special characters in it.

To fix that, and also for security reasons, you *must* use mysql_escape_string on your text before trying to insert it into the table.